# Ldap injection query explained

Tags: ldap, code-injection

I have the following code :

```
 String ldapSearchQuery = "(cn=" + $userName + ")";
     System.out.println(ldapSearchQuery);
```

> If a user puts “jonys) (| (password = * ) )”, it will generate the code bellow revealing jonys’ password ( cn = jonys ) ( | (password = * ) )

My question is (!(password=*)) is executed? I know that if there is not an & or | the next filter is not executed.I am right? I can't figure it out what happens exactly.

What (|(password=*)) means? | implies two variables but here i see only one. It is something like this (password= * |1) ?

Comment: You are correct, but what are you quoting from? That filter does not reveal anything, let alone a password. It's not a legal filter.

Comment: ok but a read in a book that in OpenLdap without & or | it is ignored. (|(password=*)) means (password=*|1) or what ? I don't understand the meaning of a varible with | in front of it. I understand if there were two variable with that | but 1 what means?

Comment: i am quoting from OWSAP